# Подключение к серверу

Tags: php, irc, бот

Выполняю подключение к серверу, после того, как выполнил подключение, сервер должен отослать команду `HAAAPSI GhDfhhAs 7` и я должен ответить на нее (`HAAAPSI` все время генерируется, т.е. `GhDfhhAs 7` - это генерированные символы).

Вот кусочек с кода:

```
<?php

  // Конфиг

  $nick = 'vova';
  $name = 'vova';
  $test = '123';

  $serv = '***************';
  $port = 6667;

  $chan = 'uid';

  // Предотвращение от остановки сценарий =)
  set_time_limit(0);

  // Выполняем подключение
  $socket = fsockopen($serv, $port) or die();

  // После этого, сервер должен выдать нам HAAAPSI ........ .

  // После того, как выдал - мы шлем следующее:
  fputs($socket,"USER $name\n"); 
  fputs($socket,"NICK $nick\n"); 
  fputs($socket,"PRIVMSG $test\n");
```

Comment: Не вижу ошибки/вопроса

Comment: ошибок нету :)

Comment: Тогда в чем Ваш вопрос?

Comment: мы должны подключиться к серверу и ждать пока сервер ответит "HAAAPSI ........ .", после этого послать то, что находится в самом низу :)

Comment: Поздравляю, а что не получается?

Comment: а где вы увидели код, который я прошу?

Comment: Я вижу кусок кода, читаю, что вам нужно что-то сделать и искренне сочувствую. В каком месте вы затрудняетесь? Научитесь уже в конце концов делать вещи в таком порядке: "руки, гугл, хэшкод". А не "хэшкод, ctrl+c, ctr+v".

Answer (score 1):

```
$socket = fsockopen($serv, $port) or die();
$ans = fgets($socket); // $ans - строка с сервера
die(var_dump($ans));
```